# Genymotion Galaxy S3 emulator missing a phone icon

Tags: android, genymotion

For some reason, my Genymotion Galaxy S3 emulator missing a phone icon. Has anyone else had this issue and has a solution?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: it's because it's not a phone. it can't make phone calls.

Comment: The google android emulators have phone icons and can simulate phone calls, so I don't see why this galaxy s3 (which is a phone) emulator does not have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genymotion emulator does not still support phone call emulation. This is the reason why there is no phone icon.

No doubt it could come further but I don't know when.